# Java NullPointerException - can I tell the null Object's class?

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception

I know java can't give me the name of the null field at run time, but in many cases having an `NullPointerException` message that contains the null Object run time class name, could probably make it much easier to trace the Exception cause. Or am I missing something and this too is impossible?

P.S. Even if there's no such standard way, can you think of a trick to get it done?

**EDIT:**
For clarification - I know I can (most of the times) trace the source easily from the code line, but:

- in some cases it will require deeper digging into the called methods (if the try block is not deep enough - which is a poor way to code but sometimes it's a given fact).
- Say some new SO guy asks about such Exception, then having the message could help us solve his problem much faster (which is true in any case of debugging from logs).

Comment: if you look closely to your error log you can easily find the exact location where the exception occured

Comment: You can read the stacktrace of error and can find which method throws exception at which line, and definitely you can find which variable is null at that line

Comment: StinePike: You get the line, but that line might still involve half a dozen references, each of which might be `null`. That being said, I never had that much of a problem finding the culprit.

Comment: @Јοеу And that's precisely why we should avoid complicated one liners.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, null is just that; null, no class, no object, just nothing.
So, it is impossible to tell you what was null.  But if you can see the source line, then it should be easy to guess what was the null the program was trying to access.

Comment: Don't the JVM knows the type of the null pointer when it tries to reference it? If not, how does it know what memory structure to expect? Isn't the virtual table being read in run time?

Comment: That check for the object type is done at compile time.  At run time it is not known.  At run time, the JVM would expect a reference to an object. See the other related questions.

Comment: Hmm.. too bad, I write a lot of one-line code and end up having to break it into multiple lines to find out which object is null.

Answer (score 3):

There is only one `null` in all Java virtual machine, not a `null` per class. So this is not possible.